# Trying to understand python, why is this function not working? [Added formulas]

Tags: python

(I added the function in question @ Bottom)

Working on my first python app.

Im making a simple rock, paper, scissors game.

I have a function that takes in two parameters:

1. The users input
2. The computers input

The function looks like this:

`seeIfUserWon(userInput, selectRandomOption())` where `selectRandomOption()` just chooses a random Enum (ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS)

The code works if I replace `selectRandomOption` with hardcoded input.

---

Currently that code gives me the error:

`ValueError: 'Paper' is not a valid RPS` where `RPS` is an Enum class with 3 cases: ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS

But like I said if I just put in RPS.ROCK for the second parameter then it works...

What am I not understanding about python.. maybe I need to use a lambda here but I'm not sure? Any references would be appreciated as well!

---

Functions I used:

```
def selectRandomOption() -> RPS:
    pick = options[random.randint(0,2)]
    return RPS(pick)
```

Options:

```
options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
```

Which I then validate with:

```
def validateUserInput(input):
  if "rock" in input.lower():
    return RPS.ROCK
  elif "paper" in input.lower():
    return RPS.PAPER
  elif "scissors" in input.lower():
    return RPS.SCISSORS
  else:
    raise Exception
```

Enum :

```
class RPS(Enum):
  ROCK        = auto()
  PAPER       = auto()
  SCISSORS    = auto()
```

Comment: What do you think `RPS(pick)` is *supposed to work*? Also, why not just put the enums in the list in the first place?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thats why I'm here asking the question.. and I wanted to learn about enum conversion

Comment: You're calling `RPS` with a string argument, but it only takes integer arguments (that's what `auto()` does, it's assigning the integers 1-3 to your Enums. Either 1) give your Enums string values (i.e.: ROCK = "rock") so that you can simply do `RPS("rock")` or put the Enums themselves into the list from which you're randomly choosing: `choice((RPS.ROCK, RPS.PAPER, RPS.SCISSORS))`.

Comment: btw, I'd suggest using a different variable name than `input` as that is the name of a built-in function and you're overwriting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than randomly picking an integer, then looking up a string, then getting an enum value, consider just choosing the enum value directly. For example:

```
import random

class RPS(Enum):
    ROCK        = auto()
    PAPER       = auto()
    SCISSORS    = auto()

random.choice(list(RPS))
# <RPS.SCISSORS: 3>
```

Comment: There are no currently downvoted answers @madbird https://i.imgur.com/FgiPbNQ.png

Comment: Thanks that worked.. was my function `selectRandom...` not returning the right case.. ?

Comment: @SergioBost it wasn't really an issue of case. To get an enum by calling it (i.e. with `(...)`, you need to pass the *value* not the name. These are integers the way you are using it. You *could* do something like `RPS['ROCK']`, but as others showed `RPS(1)` is probably better, or changing the values to strings. Still, I think it's nicer just to use `choice()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky to say for sure without seeing the seeifuserwon function but I think this is probably what's going on.

If you rewrite this function as below:

```
def selectRandomOption() -> RPS:
    pick = random.randint(1, 3)
    return RPS(pick)
```

I suspect that will fix your problem... You've defined RPS as an Enum class. To get the corresponding class member for a value you need to pass the number to the Enum class - details [here.](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html)

I also changed it to (1, 3) in the above since the count starts from 1 not 0 in the Enum class.

Comment: You also could use random.choice as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class RPS(Enum):
  ROCK        = "Rock"
  PAPER       = "Paper"
  SCISSORS    = "Scissors"
```